# Insert Array into MySQL from Parsed Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a script that parses data from HTML tables and puts it into an array. Here's the sample output from the script:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [Precinct Code] => Array
        (
            [Precinct] => Array
                (
                    [Total Registered] => Array
                        (
                            [Total Voting] => Array
                                (
                                    [Percent Voting] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [004] => Array
        (
            [AWENDAW] => Array
                (
                    [1299] => Array
                        (
                            [926] => Array
                                (
                                    [71.285] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to insert these arrays into a MySQL database, and I am using the following code:

```
    $html = file_get_html('URL GOES HERE');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $precinct = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $precinctCode = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $totalRegistered = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;
    $totalVoting = $row->find('td',3)->plaintext;
    $percentVoting = $row->find('td',4)->plaintext;

    $table[$precinctCode][$precinct][$totalRegistered][$totalVoting][$percentVoting] = true;

    /* Dump each array into MySQL table */
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MY_DATABASE_NAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    $insert = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO rsltStats (precinctCode , precinct, totalRegistered,   
      totalVoting, percentVoting ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    foreach($table as $values) {
        $insert->execute($values);
    }
}
```

However, it keeps throwing an error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

I am fairly new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is your first clue `number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` ... you do not have enough `?` setup. You should use the count of $values to figure it out dynamically.

Comment: `$values` must be an array of 5 values if you are passing it to `execute()` to populate the parameters in your query. However, it looks like `$values` is an array of even more arrays. It's actually rather unclear exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually on second thought... the way you are making that $table array may be your sole problem. Its a huge nested single array, very odd. As foreach will only do one (precinctCode being the index)... followed by 4 cells for $values, not 5.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to take the data from this table (at least the first 5 columns): https://www.scvotes.org/cgi-bin/scsec/vothistcty?ctynam=CHARLESTON&election=vhgen16&regvot=VOT and put it into my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
$table[$precinctCode][$precinct][$totalRegistered][$totalVoting][$percentVoting] = true;
...
foreach($table as $values) {
    $insert->execute($values);
}
```

This is looping on $table, which only has one row where the index is precinctCode, and then $values ends up with only 4 elements. Not 5.

Try instead simply this:

```
$values = array($precinctCode,$precinct,$totalRegistered,$totalVoting,$percentVoting);
...
$insert->execute($values);
```

IF you are needing that $table array afterwards, you can still build that $table[][][] nested array like you are, but dont use it to do the sql.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!